# Outputs differing -- can't understand the logic

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, reverse, sizeof

Basically I am creating an array 'string' with some values in it, creating another array ('auxstring'), and then storing all the values of the initial array in reverse order. Finally I print them out.

How come when I execute the program as is, I get garbage as the output? However, if I put another number in the 'string' array (ie: {3,1,1,3,4}) it works fine (outputs: 43113).

It also works fine if I add this line:

"printf("%d\n", sizeof(auxstring));"

right before the for loop.

I'm sure it's something very basic, but I would like to understand what is going on behind the scene and why adding a number at the end of the initial string, or putting that printf, somehow outputs the accurate numbers.

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    int i=0, j, l; 
    char string[] = {3,1,1,3}; 
    char auxstring[sizeof(string)];

    for (j=(sizeof(auxstring) - 1); j >= auxstring[0]; j--) {

        auxstring[j] = string[i];
        i++; 
    }

for (l=0; l < sizeof(auxstring); l++) {
    printf("%d",auxstring[l]);
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: The condition probably should be `j>=0` instead of `j >= auxstring[0]`.

Comment: %d expects ints, you are giving it a char (fewer bytes)

Comment: @drilow `char` will be promoted to `int`, so that's okay.

Comment: `auxstring` is used uninitialized in the test part of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in the for loop

```
for (j=(sizeof(auxstring) - 1); j >= auxstring[0]; j--) {
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

does not make sense because at least the array `auxstring` is not initialized.

Also the loop is complicated because it uses two variables as indices.

Ans the variables `i`, `j`, `l` should have the type `size_t` - the type of the returned value of the operator `sizeof`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char string[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    char auxstring[sizeof( string )];
    const size_t N = sizeof( string );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        auxstring[i] = string[N - i - 1];
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d", auxstring[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
4321
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer and elegant solution to my obtuse question. I am actually curious as to why adding that printf before the for  loop in my initial code prompted it to work as intended. Any idea what is going on behind the scenes?

Comment: @J.Rousselot I am sorry I have not understood your question.

Comment: @J.Rousselot It seems that adding the printf statement forces the compiler to zero-initialize the array. However you may not rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

The loop condition should be `j >= 0`.

Right now you compare against the *uninitialized* value in `auxstring[0]`, which is *indeterminate* (and will seem random).

Comment: I appreciate your quick help, that solved it.

Any idea why:

It also works fine if I add this line:

"printf("%d\n", sizeof(auxstring));"

right before the for loop.

allows the program to function?

Comment: @J.Rousselot I do not know. While using indeterminate values doesn't have to lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), you still should not trust the behavior of such a program.